# Invalid Security Check RegisteredClient when connect to MFP 8.0

Tags: objective-c, ibm-mobilefirst, mfp

When I try to call [WLAuthorizationManager sharedInstance] login with my securityCheckName.

But it still will call RegisteredClient and throw with this error.

### errorMsg: "Invalid Security Check RegisteredClient"

Anyone can help me? Appreciate =)

MFP Server Version:8.0.0.00-20160822-2140

Client Version: 8.0.2018031513

Comment: Please upgrade your server version to any version from 2018.

Comment: Also can you share the login function call?

Comment: Upgrade your server to the latest ,it is recommended  to have  both client and server levels should be  on  same level .

Comment: Okie will try this out. Thanks so much XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest client SDK requires minimum MobileFirst Server Version of Febraury 2017 and later build as it contains Default Scope `RegisteredClient` Changes.

Kindly upgrade your MobileFirst Server version to latest which will resolve the issue which you are facing.

Comment: Okie will try this out. Thanks so much XD